# How to create and subscribe an Amazon SQS queue to an Amazon SNS topic in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

How to create and subscribe an Amazon SQS queue to an Amazon SNS topic in AWS CloudFormation?

- SNS topic name = T1
- SQS queue name = Q1

I need a template in JSON or YAML

Pease help me.

Comment: Does the Amazon SNS topic already exist, or do you wish to create it in the CloudFormation template too?

Comment: i need to create that also @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [AWS::SQS::Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html) to create an Amazon SQS queue
- If required, use [AWS::SNS::Topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html) to create an Amazon SNS topic
- Use [AWS::SNS::Subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html) to subscribe the SQS queue to the SNS topic

Here is an example from [Create a Subscription Between an Amazon SQS Queue and an Amazon SNS Topic in AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-sns-subscribe-cloudformation/):

```yaml
Parameters:
  SNSTopicARN:
    Type: String
    Description: awsSNSTopicArnExample 
  TopicRegion:
    Type: String
    Description: us-east-1

Resources:
  Queue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

  SnsSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol: sqs
      Endpoint: !GetAtt Queue.Arn
      Region: !Ref TopicRegion
      TopicArn: !Ref SNSTopicARN
```

Comment: sir i need like this yaml file can u able to help. 
       i) Create Topic T1
       ii) Create Queue Q1
      iii) subscription T1 to Q1
      iV) Publish Message M1 to T1
      v) read Meassage M1 from Q1
        vi)  Print it

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service for asking other people to write code / template. We are happy to help if you face a problem. I suggest you start by reviewing the documentation pages that I linked, including the page with the template sample that I included in my answer and try to create the template yourself. Let us know if you have any specific issues with the template.

Comment: The CloudFormation template can create the SNS topic, the SQS and the subscription between them, but it will not process messages (publish, read, print). That should be done by separate software that you run for processing messages from the queue.

Comment: Yes, I reviewed that page but it's not suited for me, that's the reason I came for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't see any way to know de date/hour that a message is received through amazon SNS? Is it not possible?

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorim Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on a question that asks something different.